# How to pass Java color into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, colors

I am creating a chat web application using Spring and I have a color input box that gets color from each user. I created the variable, col, in Javascript that would get the value of the color from the Message class.

```
function sendMessage(event) {
    var messageContent = messageInput.value.trim();
    if(messageContent && stompClient) {
        var chatMessage = {
            sender: username,
            content: messageInput.value,
            type: 'CHAT',
            color: col
        };
        stompClient.send("/app/chat.sendMessage", {}, JSON.stringify(chatMessage));
        messageInput.value = '';
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I get the error:

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: 
Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of `java.awt.Color` (although at least one Creator exists): 
no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('#fff300')
at [Source: (byte[])"{"sender":"testing","content":"test message","type":"CHAT","color":"#fff300"}"; 
line: 1, column: 68] (through reference chain: com.chatio.websocketdemo.model.ChatMessage["color"]);
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException:
Cannot construct instance of `java.awt.Color` (although at least one Creator exists): 
no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('#fff300')
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your message object on the server side has a member that is a `java.awt.Color`. You should instead change its type to `String`, so that the hexadecimal string you send can be converted from the JSON. If you want to create a `Color` object from the `String`, you can use [`Color.decode(hexString);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#decode(java.lang.String))

Comment: I have tried hardcoding a hexadecimal color into where I put the variable col, but that showed the same error

Comment: @DBalani Did you change the variable's type to a String?

Comment: Should I change the type in the Java class?

Comment: @DBalani Yes, that is what my answer is about.